# Cannot get Apple's SimpleScripting example to work when using NSApplicationDelegate

Tags: cocoa, properties, applescript, sdef, nsapplication-delegate

I am trying to write a trivial Objective-C application:  I just want an app that will display a word in the status bar and allow the word to be updated via AppleScript.  To be honest, I know little about AppleScript and nothing about Objective-C.  But, it can't be that hard because it only took me 2 hours to get a menubar app that has menu items and responds to core AppleScript commands like "quit", so I'm 95% of the way there.  Unfortunately, I spent the next 6 hours try to find some way of giving this application a simple property I can get and set through AppleScript.

Here is my .h code:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate> {
    NSWindow *window;
    IBOutlet NSMenu *statusMenu;
    NSStatusItem *statusItem;
}
@property (assign) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;
- (NSString*) foobaz;
@end
```

The `foobaz` method is the one that I was using to try to make a readable property (`*window` is part of the boilerplate I was given by XCode and not relevant to the issue at hand).  Here is my .sdef file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE dictionary SYSTEM "file://localhost/System/Library/DTDs/sdef.dtd">
<dictionary xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2003/XInclude">
  <xi:include
    href="file:///System/Library/ScriptingDefinitions/CocoaStandard.sdef"
    xpointer="xpointer(/dictionary/suite)"/>
  <suite name="StatusMenuApp suite" code="smas"
    description="StatusMenuApp specific classes.">
    <class name="application" code="smaa" inhereits="application"
      description="Application object.">
      <cocoa class="AppDelegate"/>
      <property name="foobaz" code="smas" type="text" access="r"/>
    </class>
  </suite>
</dictionary>
```

So I've got it set up just like the SimpleScripting example from Apple here: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/SimpleScripting/Introduction/Intro.html

However, I've tried running this in the script editor:

```
tell application "StautsMenuApp"
    properties
end tell
```

And I just get a list of the core properties, with no mention of `foobaz` whatsoever, unlike Apple's example, in which the custom property appears alongside the core properties when I run it.

I feel like I've tried a hundred variations on this and read a hundred examples but can't get anything to work.  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

There are numerous issues with your SDEF file.

1. While this isn't a major issue, when defining your own "types" (`OSType` codes), all lowercase letters are historically reserved for Apple. So, you should do something like `'Smas'` or `'sMas'` but not `'smas'`.
2. It may have been a typo here in the web browser, but you misspelled `inhereits` in the line `<class name="application" code="smaa" inhereits="application"...`. It's important that the spelling is correct so that you can properly "extend" the base AppleScript `application` class with your own additional properties. This may be the reason why you're only seeing the default application properties in AppleScript Editor. (While correcting the spelling alone may allow things to work, there are other corrections you should make as well).
3. You're trying to specify that the Cocoa class for your "extended" `application` AppleScript class is `AppDelegate`, but this is problematic because `AppDelegate` does not inherit from `NSApplication` like specified in Apple's example .sdef, rather, it inherits from plain-old `NSObject`.

Before moving on to how I would re-write the SDEF, I'll review what the basic idea is behind how Apple's example SDEF works to add custom properties to the default AppleScript `application` class. The AppleScript `application` class corresponds to the `NSApplication` Cocoa class. When you launch your application, OS X creates an instance of `NSApplication` (or a subclass thereof, as specified by the `NSPrincipalClass` entry in the app's Info.plist file). This instance manages the application. In Cocoa, there are 2 possible ways to add the additional AppleScript properties to the existing `NSApplication` class: 1) create a custom subclass of `NSApplication` which contain the additional properties or 2) use an Objective-C category to extend the existing `NSApplication` class as-is. (In Cocoa, Objective-C categories are a way to add additional functionality to an existing class without the potential complexities that subclassing introduces). Apple's `SimpleScripting` example uses the latter approach (Objective-C categories) to add the additional functionality.

Below is how I would rewrite the SDEF.

SimpleScriptingAppDelegate.sdef:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE dictionary SYSTEM "file://localhost/System/Library/DTDs/sdef.dtd">
<dictionary xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2003/XInclude">
    <xi:include
    href="file:///System/Library/ScriptingDefinitions/CocoaStandard.sdef"
    xpointer="xpointer(/dictionary/suite)"/>
    <suite name="StatusMenuApp suite" code="SSAD"
                 description="StatusMenuApp-specific classes.">
        <class name="application" code="capp" inherits="application"
                                 description="Application object.">
            <cocoa class="NSApplication"/>
            <property name="foobaz" code="Foob"
                description="Description of the foobaz property." type="text">
                <cocoa key="foobaz"/>
            </property>
        </class>
    </suite>
</dictionary>
```

You'll notice that I've specified that I'm creating a custom AppleScript `application` class that inherits from the standard AppleScript `application` class. I've specified that the Cocoa class for this custom `application` is `NSApplication`. I've added a custom AppleScript property whose name is `foobaz` and whose type is `text`. (The AppleScript `text` class will correspond to the Cocoa `NSString` class). Also important is that I've specified that the Cocoa key to access this custom property is `foobaz`. This "Cocoa key" specifies the name of the Objective-C method that will be used to provide the value for the property. The configuration defined above specifies that the custom `foobaz` property can be obtained by calling the `foobaz` method on the shared instance of the `NSApplication` object.

To implement that in the Cocoa side of things, I defined the `(MDScriptingAdditions)` category on `NSApplication` like shown below:

MDNSApplicationScriptingAdditions.h:

```
@interface NSApplication (MDScriptingAdditions)

- (NSString *)foobaz;
- (void)setFoobaz:(NSString *)aFoobaz;

@end
```

MDNSApplicationScriptingAdditions.m:

```
#import "MDNSApplicationScriptingAdditions.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@implementation NSApplication (MDScriptingAdditions)

- (NSString *)foobaz {
    return [(AppDelegate *)[NSApp delegate] foobaz];
}

- (void)setFoobaz:(NSString *)aFoobaz {
    return [(AppDelegate *)[NSApp delegate] setFoobaz:aFoobaz];
}
@end
```

You can see that I basically forward the handling of these methods to the `AppDelegate` class, which is how you wanted to set things up.

AppDelegate.h:

```
@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate> {
    IBOutlet NSWindow                    *window;
    IBOutlet NSTextField                *foobazTextField;

    NSString                            *foobaz;
}
- (NSString *)foobaz;
- (void)setFoobaz:(NSString *)aFoobaz;
@end
```

This setup allows you to get and set the custom `foobaz` property via AppleScript. Setting the value will cause the value shown in the `foobaz:` text field to change to the value you set like shown in the image below:

[image]

Sample project: [SimpleScriptingAppDelegate.zip](http://www.markdouma.com/developer/SimpleScriptingAppDelegate.zip)

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I see offhand is a problem in your sdef. The code for this line needs to be "capp". That's standard and this will be the same in any sdef file. It is defined by Apple so you need that.

```
<class name="application" code="smaa" inhereits="application"
      description="Application object.">
```

After you do that, you would access that method like this...

```
tell application "StautsMenuApp" to foobaz
```